# WebSocket connection failed with Java 11, Glassfish 6.2.1 and Java EE 9

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish

I'm trying to create a simple web socket server with Java EE. I want to create a simple chat app but I'm getting this error, saying `WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/chat/ws' failed:` and nothing else.

Here is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>chat-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>chat-app</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>chat</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the `ChatServer.java`:

```java
@ServerEndpoint("/ws")
public class ChatServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void open(Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Welcome");
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm trying to connect to the web socket:

```js
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/chat/ws");
```

I'm actually following [this](https://jckjaer.dk/2017/06/07/java-websocket-server-in-intellij-idea/) tutorial which uses Glassfish 4. Also, I don't know if this has anything to do with it but I'm using IntelliJ.

Any ideas?

P.S. Tried Tomcat too, same result. The issue must be with IntelliJ.

Comment: Title says Java 11, but your POM says Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it would be something like a wrong import to ruin a weekend.

I needed to import

```java
import jakarta.websocket.EncodeException;
import jakarta.websocket.OnClose;
import jakarta.websocket.OnMessage;
import jakarta.websocket.OnOpen;
import jakarta.websocket.Session;
import jakarta.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
```

instead of from

```java
import javax.websocket.server*;
```

Comment: Your title says Java EE 8, but that uses javax.* package, not jakarta.* package — for jakarta.* package you would be using Jakarta EE 9 or later. And for Java 11, you should be using Jakarta EE 9.1 implementations.